# google_sign_in plugin of Flutter : Something Went Wrong error(PlatformException(sign_in_failed, com.google.android.gms.common.api.b: 10: ,null, null))

Tags: android, flutter, firebase-authentication, flutter-dependencies, google-signin

When i use google_sign_in plugin for Google Signin Service and Run my app at that time it shows one dialogue box for choose an account for login ....
But when i choose an Account then it shows following error in *Catch Block* (as per image)

```
Future<UserCredential?> _signInWithGoogle() async {

try {

  await InternetAddress.lookup('google.com');

  // Trigger the authentication flow

  final GoogleSignInAccount? googleUser = await GoogleSignIn().signIn();

  // Obtain the auth details from the request

  final GoogleSignInAuthentication? googleAuth =

      await googleUser?.authentication;

  // Create a new credential

  final credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(

    accessToken: googleAuth?.accessToken,

    idToken: googleAuth?.idToken,

  );

  // Once signed in, return the UserCredential

  return await APIs.auth.signInWithCredential(credential);

} catch (e) {

  log('\n_signInWithGoogle: $e');

  Dialogs.showSnackbar(context, 'Something Went Wrong ($e)');

  return null;

}
```

}

**Flutter app is already connected with Firebase and Authentication also On and Sha1 key is also uploaded....**

How can i solve this problem?

[image: While Login in Real Device]